# Projecting nested documents in Mongo

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to find and project from a nested structure. For example, I have the following document where each unit might have an embedded sub-unit:

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "unit" : {
        "_id" : 2,
        "unit" : {
            "_id" : 3,
            "unit" : {
                "_id" : 4
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And I want to get the id's of all the subunits under unit 1:

```
[{_id:2}, {_id:3}, {_id:4}]
```

`$graphlookup` does not seem to handle this kind of nested structure. As far as I understand, it works when the units are saved at a single level without nesting and each keep a reference to its parent unit.

What is the correct way to retrieve the desired result?

Comment: Does [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/VC_9x7h9f4r) help?

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet Since I do not know in advance the depth of nesting, there needs to be a recursive logic.

Comment: Then you should rethink of your schema design because none of the aggregation produces such type of result

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, [`$graphlookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/) isn't operator for your problem, because it's recursive search on a `collection`, not recursive in a `document`

> $graphLookup Performs a recursive search on a collection, with options
>   for restricting the search by recursion depth and query filter.

Therefore, it didn't recursive search in your document, it only recursive search on a collection (includes multiple documents), it cannot handle your problem.

With your problem, I think it is not responsibility of Mongo, because you've retrieved your wanted document. You want to parse the retrieved document to array of sub-documents, you can do it in your language.

Example if you use JavaScript (Node.JS for backend), you can parse this document to array:

```js
const a = {
  "_id": 1,
  "unit": {
    "_id": 2,
    "unit": {
      "_id": 3,
      "unit": {
        "_id": 4
      }
    }
  }
}

const parse = o => {
  const { _id } = o;
  if (!o.unit) return [{ _id }];
  return [{ _id }, ...parse(o.unit) ];
}

console.log(parse(a.unit));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do that from mongodb query. Mongodb will guarantee the document with `id :1`, and will not recursively search inside the document. 
What you can do is: retrieve the document from mongodb, then parse it into a Map object and retrieve the information from that map, recursively.